# How to calculate the geodesic equation for radial acceleration in general relativity?

Tags: metric-tensor, relativity

how do you calculate $\frac{d^2r}{d\tau^2}$ in the geodesic equation:
$$\frac{d^2x^m}{d\tau^2}+\Gamma_{pq}^m\frac{dx^p}{d\tau}\frac{dx^q}{d\tau}=0$$

I can figure out the Christoffel symbols but I get stuck on the derivatives $\frac{dx^p}{d\tau}$. I am interested in the Schwarschild metric:

$$ds^2=-c^2d\tau^2=(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r})c^2dt^2-(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r})^{-1}dr^2-r^2d\phi-r^2\sin^2{\phi} d\varphi^2$$

This is how far I've gotten:

$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
    (1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r})c^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & (1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r})^{-1} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & r^2 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & r^2\sin^2{\phi}\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\Gamma_{mn}^t=\frac 12 g^{st}(\partial_mg_{sn}+\partial_ng_{sm}-\partial_sg_{mn})$$
I then calculated the non vanishing Christoffel symbols and expanded the geodesic equation. I won't type out the christoffel symbols but you'll get the idea.

$$\frac{d^2x^m}{d^2\tau}=-\Gamma_{pq}^m\frac{dx^p}{d\tau}\frac{dx^q}{d\tau}=-\sum_p\sum_q\Gamma_{pq}^m\frac{dx^p}{d\tau}\frac{dx^q}{d\tau}$$

I am only interested in the radial axis. So we can replace $\Gamma_{pq}^m$ by $\Gamma_{pq}^r$. The non vanishing Christoffel symbols for $\Gamma_{pq}^r$ are $\Gamma_{tt}^r$, $\Gamma_{rr}^r$, $\Gamma_{\phi\phi}^r$ and $\Gamma_{\varphi\varphi}^r$.
$$-\sum_p\sum_q\Gamma_{pq}^r\frac{dx^p}{d\tau}\frac{dx^q}{d\tau}=-\Gamma_{tt}^r(\frac{dt}{d\tau})^2-\Gamma_{rr}^r(\frac{dr}{d\tau})^2-\Gamma_{\phi\phi}^r(\frac{d\phi}{d\tau})^2-\Gamma_{\varphi\varphi}^r(\frac{d\varphi}{d\tau})^2$$

When assuming that $\frac{dt}{d\tau}=1$ and the other derivatives are 0. I can reduce it to:
$$\frac{d^2r}{d\tau^2}=\ddot r=\frac{GM}{r^2}(1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r})$$
This is just Newtonian gravitation with a little correction. Is this a good approximation? And coming back to the question, what would the exact equation be: how can I calculate the derivatives $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$, $\frac{dr}{d\tau}$, $\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}$ and $\frac{d\varphi}{d\tau}$?

Comment: Take a look at this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics).

Comment: @Pulsar I assume you mean the "Mathematical derivations of the orbital equation" part. I can't understand why they devide the radial equation by $\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}$ and $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$. Why is this neccesary and does this help? I expect my final answer to be a function r dubbledot of r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need code for the Schwarzschild and Kerr metrics then see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189961/interpreting-mathematica-code-on-black-holes/190011#190011). If you just need geodesic equations, then put $r_g=2GM/c^2$ and $c = 1$. We number the coordinates $(t, r, \theta, \phi)$ as (0,1,2,3). Nonzero components of Christoffel symbols have the form:
$$\Gamma ^0_{10}=\frac {r_g}{2r(r-r_g)}, \Gamma ^1_{00}=\frac {(r-r_g)r_g}{2r^3}, \Gamma ^1_{11}=-\frac {r_g}{2r(r-r_g)},\Gamma ^1_{22}=r_g-r, \Gamma ^1_{33}=(r_g-r)\sin^2\theta, \Gamma ^2_{21}=\frac {1}{r}, \Gamma ^2_{33}=-\cos \theta \sin \theta, \Gamma ^3_{31}=\frac {1}{r}, \Gamma ^3_{32}=\cot \theta $$
Accordingly, the equations have the form
$$t''+\frac {2r_gr't'}{2r(r-r_g)}=0$$
$$r''-\frac {r_gr'^2}{2r(r-r_g)}+\frac {(r-r_g)r_gt'^2}{2r^3}+(r_g-r)\theta '^2-(r-r_g)\sin ^2\theta \phi '^2=0$$
$$\theta ''+\frac {2r'\theta '}{r}-\cos \theta \sin \theta \phi '^2=0$$
$$\phi ''+\frac {2r'\phi '}{r}+2\cot \theta \theta '\phi '=0
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @jessegerritsen You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The geodesic equation is a set of coupled second-order ordinary differential equations for the geodesic path $x^m(\tau)$ that happen to also include first derivatives in a nonlinear way. You can’t calculate $dx^m/d\tau$ *before* solving for the geodesics. After you solve the set of equations you can easily differentiate the path to compute these derivatives.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I solve the geodesics withouth knowing the derivatives? I have no background in physics or calculus. I just graduated from high school and took a few online standford lectures. What kind of calculus do I need in order to solve equations like this?

Comment: An undergraduate physics program typically requires a entire math course just on techniques for solving differential equations, so how to solve the geodesic equation is not something I can explain in a comment. Before studying differential equations you study calculus and, often, vector calculus. For example, you need to be able to integrate to solve some differential equations.